# Flutter Edamam no data response

Tags: flutter, rest, flutter-http

I am currently trying to learn rest APIs. I want to program a food app and I'm using the Edamam food database.
https://developer.edamam.com/food-database-api-docs

If I do a request on the browser with a sample link:

[https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser?app_id="myOwnAppId"&app_key="myOwnAppKey"&ingr=apple&nutrition-type=cooking](https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser?app_id=%22myOwnAppId%22&app_key=%22myOwnAppKey%22&ingr=apple&nutrition-type=cooking).

Then I also get a response and all the data in JSON format.

But in Flutter I only get an error and no data output.

The code:

getFoods(String query) async {
String url = "api.edamam.com";

```
var response = await http.get(Uri.https("api.edamam.com",
    "/api/food-database/v2/parser?app_id=$appID&app_key=$appKey&ingr=$query&nutrition-type=cooking"));

print(response.body); //Output{"status" : "error", "message" : null }
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

I think the problem is the second parameter in Uri.https()? i don't know what should go in there

Comment: try this once `var headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};`
 `var res = await http.get(YOUR_WHOLE_URL, headers: headers); `

Comment: Yeah I got it now. I understood the headers.
This is what I need:


var response = await http
        .get(Uri.https("api.edamam.com", "/api/food-database/v2/parser", {
      "app_id": "$appID",
      "app_key": "$appKey",
      "ingr": "$query",
      "nutrition-type": "cooking",
    }));